# Trying remote tasklist in cmd.exe on Windows 7 Pro but getting RPC server error

Tags: windows-7, command-line, remote-desktop, windows-server-2003, rpc

I have a Windows 7 Pro PC that is on my company domain.  We have a Windows Server 2003 R2 domain controller and I have a domain administrator account that is a local administrator on all the office computers.

I'm trying to use `tasklist` in cmd remotely from my Win 7 Pro pc to get the tasks on the other computers in the office.  I was successful on one Windows 7 pc but when I try the following command...:

```
tasklist /s pcname /u domain\user /p password
```

all the other computers (windows 7 and windows 10) (except the one windows 7) think for a minute then give the following response in cmd:

```
ERROR: RPC server is unavailable.
```

Why would it work on one computer remotely but not the others when they are all on the domain and I am a local and domain admin on all of them?  I am also able to access each one with remote desktop.

This would be very helpful because there is occasionally services I need to kill and doing so remotely would be very convenient as our offices are a pretty good walk away from each other.  Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

For you to issue a remote tasklist command, the following conditions must exist:

- The target must be running the following system services :
  DCOM Server Process Launcher, Remote Procedure Call (RPC) and RPC Endpoint Mapper.
- On the target, in Control Panel > Windows Defender Firewall,
  click on "Allow an app through Windows Firewall",
  and scroll down to enable "Remote Assistance".
- When running Network Connections (`ncpa.cpl`), right-click the network connection,
  Properties, must enable "File and Printer Sharing for Microsoft Networks" and
  "Internet Protocol Version 6 (TCP/IPv6)".

You could avoid all this by using from the
[PsTools suite](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/sysinternals/downloads/pstools)
either of the utilities
[PsExec](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/sysinternals/downloads/psexec),
[PsList](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/sysinternals/downloads/pslist)
or
[PsService](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/sysinternals/downloads/psservice).
They all accept the parameter of `\\computer` with `-u` (user) and `-p` (password).